# I have problem with AutoField in my model and seqence in oracle database

Tags: django, oracle

I use Legacy database oracle 11g and there are a seqences.

If I remove `number_mymodel` field from my model i have an error: ***ORA-00904: "MYMODEL"."ID": invalid identifier***

if i try

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number_mymodel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True ,auto_created=True)
    ...
```

it's work, but if I want add in my django admin panel **number_Mymodel** is **NULL** so I can't add it.

What should I do with my sequence in database or in my model?
I want that, if I'm adding in django panel it will be autoincrement `number_mymodel`in my database.

Comment: Did you try to run makemigrations and migrate command after the change?

Comment: @Anshul Sharma of course yes